# optimize mysql join query using indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have the index `complex1(field2,field3)` for searching in `table1` and `index order1(field10)` for ordering the results. The `table1` is MySQL InndoDB table. By sub-query I try to obtain values using `complex1` index, and by main query I want to order them using `order1` index and leave only first 50.

```
  EXPLAIN(
SELECT `t1`.`field1`,`t1`.`field10` from `database`.`table1` `t1` INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT `field1` FROM `database`.`table1` WHERE 
   `field2` >= 'val1' and `field2`<='val2' `and `field3` >= 'val3' and `field3`<='val4'
   ) as e1 
ON e1.`field1`=t1.`field1` ORDER BY t1.`field10` LIMIT 50)
```

The results are following:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13  "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   PRIMARY t1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   e1.field1   1   
2   DERIVED table1  range   complex1    complex1    8   NULL    13  "Using where; Using index"
```

As I see `complex1` is used and `order1` doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has [good documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on how indexes are used

Your subquery uses the `complex` index by scanning all the values in the range for `field2`. If `field1` is a primary key, then that is also in the InnoDB index (as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html)), so all the fields can be satisfied in the index.

Then you are doing a join on `field1`.  Because this index exists on the table, MySQL is probably using the primary index on the table for this join.  Hence, the results are then ordered by `field1` and *not* `field10`.  So, it has to do a filesort to get the final ordered results.

If `field1` is a primary key, doesn't this query do the same thing?

```
SELECT `field1`, `field10`
FROM `database`.`table1`
WHERE `field2` >= 'val1' and `field2`<='val2' `and
      `field3` >= 'val3' and `field3`<='val4'
order by field10 desc
limit 30
```

Comment: Field1 is primary key, so Innodb automatically makes complex index as (field1,field2,field3). The question was how to order using index on field10, not filesort. Now it seems as a redundant index

Comment: @AntonGuba . . . `field` would actually be the *last* key in the index, not the first, so the index is essentially `(field2, field3, field1)`.  I cannot readily think of way to modify the query or index structure to use both an index for the join and an index for the sort.